# Returning an array with every other number

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that takes an array as input and removes all the odd indices. It compiles but does not run. For some reason it flags the while loop. I am nor sure how to fix this problem.

Thanks

```
public class MoreArrayProblems
{
    public int[] everyOther (int [] a){
        if (a.length < 2){
        return a;

        }

        int []l = new int[a.length/2];
        //if (a.length%2==0) {int l[]= new int [a.length/2];}
        //else {l[] = int [a.length + 1 / 2];}

        int loc= 0, i = 1;
        while ( i<a.length){
            l[i] = a[i-1];   //for some reason this doesn't work
            i += 2;

        }

        return l;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please describe the error. What does it say?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at MoreArrayProblems.everyOther(MoreArrayProblems.java:22)

Comment: It is a runtime error

Comment: Array l is half the length of array a, but you loop to the end of a. Hence l[I] is out of range halfway through.

Comment: If you step through your code with a debugger, understanding _what_ an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means, it should be clear why you get one.

Comment: I think the condition of your while loop is the `length` of a, however the size of your `l` array is shorter than `a.size()`,so `i` will eventually be bigger than the size of `l`, therefore you get the exception out of bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), with the addition of a helpful debugging statement.

```
  import  java.util.Arrays;
public class MoreArrayProblems
{
  public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
        (new MoreArrayProblems()).everyOther(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})));
  }
    public int[] everyOther (int [] a){
        if (a.length < 2){
        return a;

        }

        int []l = new int[a.length/2];
        //if (a.length%2==0) {int l[]= new int [a.length/2];}
        //else {l[] = int [a.length + 1 / 2];}

        int loc= 0, i = 1;
        while ( i<a.length){
System.out.println("l.length=" + l.length + ", a.length=" + a.length + ", i=" + i + ", [i - 1]=" + (i - 1) + "");
            l[i] = a[i-1];   //for some reason this doesn't work
            i += 2;

        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java MoreArrayProblems
l.length=5, a.length=10, i=1, [i - 1]=0
l.length=5, a.length=10, i=3, [i - 1]=2
l.length=5, a.length=10, i=5, [i - 1]=4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at MoreArrayProblems.everyOther(MoreArrayProblems.java:21)
        at MoreArrayProblems.main(MoreArrayProblems.java:5)
```

The *first element* in an array has an *index* of `0`, not `1`. That fact, and the above debugging output reveal some pretty big problems.

Comment: Okay, thank you all have been very help, I just now need to figure out how to remove all the empty indices/zeros. I think have have some code from before that will do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MoreArrayProblems {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int divider = 2;
        int[] a = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600};
        int[] l = new int[a.length/divider];

        int i = 0;
        while ( i<l.length){
            l[i] = a[i*divider];
            System.out.println(l[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is using 'loc' fo your array 'l'. Something like this:

```
public int[] everyOther(int[] a) {
    if (a.length < 2) {
        return a;

    }

    int[] l = new int[a.length / 2];

    int loc = 0, i = 0;
    System.out.println("size: " + a.length);
    while (i < a.length) {
        if (!isOdd(a[i])){
            l[loc] = a[i];
            loc++;
        }
        i++;            

    }

    return l;
}
```

This is the `isOdd` function

```
public boolean isOdd(int number) {
    return number % 2 != 0;
}
```

Since `l.lenght` is set as `a.length/2` this code will work only if size of array `a` is a even number.For instance, if the `a.legth` = 9 then `l` will be only 4 and this will cause an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the while loop is executed

Comment: "It will work only if size of array a is a even number..." Can you elaborate on that a bit?